# IE browser automatically changed while page redirection

Tags: asp.net

I have done my project in asp.net with using webmethod concepts. I deployed it in live server. Clients are using windows 8 with IE 11/9. When users used my projects then IE version are changed to IE7. webmethod and json does not support IE 7/8. but when this page open then its automatically IE version changed and display 'JSON object' error. I tried to changed IE default version 9.but its automatically changed IE 7/8. how to change IE default version 9. what is the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are talking about the compatibility mode. Try adding following meta tag in your layout page or master page.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

The X-UA-Compatible meta tag allows web authors to choose what version of Internet Explorer the page should be rendered as.

You can read more about this at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx